# Delphi XE - F1027 Unit not found: 'System.pas' or binary equivalents (.dcu) upon Activation of trial version

Tags: delphi, build, delphi-xe, delphi-units

I just purchased the full version of Delphi XE Architect after using the trial version for 30 days.  I can't build anything, every time I go to build a project I get the error.

```
[DCC Fatal Error] MegaMainPrj.dpr(1): F1027 Unit not found: 'System.pas' or binary equivalents (.dcu)
```

A quick google said that the library paths were a problem and I compared what was given (in a previous stackoverflow question) with what I had in the registry, and it was identical.

What could be causing this?

EDIT: Immediatly after I get this error message the entire IDE crashes.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Make sure you have the environmental variables set properly (`Tools->Options->Environmental Variables` from the IDE's main menu):

```
BDS=D:\Embarcadero\RAD Studio\8.0
BDSCOMMONDIR=C:\Users\Public\Documents\RAD Studio\8.0
PLATFORM=Win32
```

These should all be set in the `System Variables` section, and should have been added by the installer. (Obviously, they should point to the installation location of your XE installation - mine is installed in `D:\Embarcadero\RAD Studio\8.0`, as you can see.)

EDIT: I see in your comment you installed in `C:\Program Files` - bad idea if you're running Windows Vista or Win7 or higher. You should try installing in a different location. You can also try running the IDE as Administrator (right-click shortcut in Start->All Programs->Embarcadero->RAD Studio XE->Delphi XE, choose "Run as Administrator" from context menu). Does this change anything?

Also, you can open a free support case at [Embarcadero](http://support.embarcadero.com) for installation-related issues. I'd first try reinstalling in another location (running the install as Administrator, putting it in another folder, and installing for all users); if that doesn't work, open a support case. You can also post to the [Embarcadero Delphi Installation forums](https://forums.embarcadero.com/forum.jspa?forumID=56) - you'll need to have already created a user account there first to log in.

Comment: BDS=c:\program files\embarcadero\rad studio\8.0; BDSCOMMONDIR=C:\Users\Public\Documents\RAD Studio\8.0;
Platform=Win32;      Looks like it's correct already.

Comment: Running as Administrator didn't fix it.  I'll uninstall, I was avoiding this because I have about a dozen third party components installed already.

Comment: @Daisetsu: Export the registry settings prior to uninstalling. You can edit the text .reg file, deleting stuff not related to your third party packages (including entire sections if needed), adjust paths if needed, and import back to the registry after reinstalling and running the IDE at least once. (The first run completes registry setup, adding entries not placed by the installer.) If this is more work than just reinstalling the third party stuff, then go ahead and reinstall the 3rd party stuff - use whatever method is less work and that you're comfortable with doing. :)

Answer (score 42):

add this :
$(BDSLIB)\win32\release;

to your library path .

Comment: This worked for me, I accidentally remove some library folder entries.

Comment: If it's a 64 bit thing failing to build make sure the 64 bit library path has `$(BDSLIB)\win64\release`

Comment: This applies when one has the "stupid" idea of pressing "Delete invalid paths" from the options menu.

Answer (score 3):

```
C:\Embarcadero\RAD Studio\9.0\lib\win32\release
```

**and**

```
C:\Embarcadero\RAD Studio\9.0\lib\win32\debug
```

**Both** of these path have been to add in Delphi XE2 from IDE <<**Tools->Options->Library->Library path**>>

It's OK?

Comment: Mine is set to "$(BDSLIB)\$(Platform)\release", just to be sure.

Answer (score 3):

Goto Tools->Options->Library->Library path

and add `$(BDSLIB)\win32\release`

This worked in Delphi 10.2

Comment: Delphi 10.3 here, this worked as well.

Answer (score 1):

When compiling using the command line compiler, so not from within the IDE, you can also get this error when the name of the build configuration is not "debug" and not "release".

It seems that, when using the command line compiler, it tries to find its dcus in a path under BDSLIB that it constructs using the configuration name.
I had this happening when using a configuration named ReleaseHA. Note: it was not a sub configuration under "release", but an extra configuration besides "debug" and "release".

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes this error message occurs when we have duplicate libraries included.

Make sure that:

**Tools->Options->Environmental Options->Library**

and

**Project->Options->Directories/Conditionals**

Don't include the same paths...

Answer (score 0):

Running as Administrator worked for me.