# Cannot build after reinstalling XE2

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Delphi XE - F1027 Unit not found: 'System.pas' or binary equivalents (.dcu) upon Activation of trial version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5656975/delphi-xe-f1027-unit-not-found-system-pas-or-binary-equivalents-dcu-upon)

I had to format myu win7 machine so i reinstalled Delphi XE2 from scratch (Embarcadero® RAD Studio XE2 Version 16.0.4429.46931 ). 
After installing it I installed all my third party components (some of them were not for Update 4, like SDAC from Devart, I had v 6.1).

Now if I do a new VCL Forms application and build it (so no logic, just an empty form) I have:

```
[DCC Fatal Error] Project1.dpr(1): F1027 Unit not found: 'System.pas' or binary equivalents `(.dcu)`
```

My first thought is uninstall all and reinstall, but do you have a clue?

Where should I start from?

Thanks.

Comment: ain't SDAC u4-ready now ? http://www.devart.com/sdac/compatibility.html

Comment: Check v6.2 http://www.devart.com/sdac/history.html

Answer (score 3):

1) Tools / Options / Environment / Delphi / Library - check correct paths

2) sysinternals Process Monitor, filter file accesses, filter by path cotaining "system." - look in which folders dcc tries to get that file instead of correct path

Comment: thanks, i checked and C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\RAD Studio\9.0\lib\win64\release is in path (also 32) the problem persists

Comment: there are more than just one path. and you did not tell in which folders files are really searched for.